# SQL to find sum of total days in a window for a series of changes

Tags: sql, window-functions, vertica

Following is the table:

| start_date | recorded_date | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-10 | 2021-11-01 | 1a |
| 2021-11-08 | 2021-11-02 | 1a |
| 2021-11-11 | 2021-11-03 | 1a |
| 2021-11-10 | 2021-11-04 | 1a |
| 2021-11-10 | 2021-11-05 | 1a |

I need a query to find the total day changes in aggregate for a given id. In this case, it changed from 10th Nov to 8th Nov so 2 days, then again from 8th to 11th Nov so 3 days and again from 11th to 10th for a day, and finally from 10th to 10th, that is 0 days.

In total there is a change of 2+3+1+0 = 6 days for the id - '1a'.

Basically for each change there is a recorded_date, so we arrange that in ascending order and then calculate the aggregate change of days grouped by id. The final result should be like:

| id | Agg_Change |
| --- | --- |
| 1a | 6 |

Is there a way to do this using SQL. I am using vertica database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking lag function will provide me the answer, but it kept giving me wrong answer because I had the wrong logic in one place. I have the answer I need:

```
with cte as(
select id, start_date, recorded_date,
row_number() over(partition by id order by recorded_date asc) as idrank,
lag(start_date,1) over(partition by id order by recorded_date asc) as prev
from table_temp
)
select id, sum(abs(date(start_date) - date(prev))) as Agg_Change
from cte
group by 1
```

If someone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you can use window function lead to get the difference between rows and then group by id

```
select id, sum(daydiff) Agg_Change
from (
select id, abs(datediff(day, start_Date, lead(start_date,1,start_date) over (partition by id order by recorded_date))) as daydiff
from tablename
) t group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed the use of `LAG()` to get the previous date in an OLAP query, and an outer query getting the absolute date difference, and the sum of it, grouping by id:

```
WITH
-- your input - don't use in real query ...
indata(start_date,recorded_date,id) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2021-11-10',DATE '2021-11-01','1a'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-08',DATE '2021-11-02','1a'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-11',DATE '2021-11-03','1a'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-10',DATE '2021-11-04','1a'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-10',DATE '2021-11-05','1a'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
w_lag AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , start_date
  , LAG(start_date) OVER w AS prevdt
FROM indata
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY recorded_date)
)
SELECT
  id
, SUM(ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,start_date,prevdt))) AS dtdiff
FROM w_lag
GROUP BY id
-- out  id | dtdiff 
-- out ----+--------
-- out  1a |      6
```